# Питон, Задача по файлам

Tags: python, файлы

> Дан файл f, компоненты которого являются целыми числами. Получить файл g, образованный из файла f исключением повторных вхождений одного и того же числа.

Вот мой код

```
import re
f = open ("f.txt","r+")

n = f.read()
nums = set(re.findall('-?\d+', n))

g = open("g.txt","w+")
lst=[]

for a in nums:
    lst.append(a)
    g.write(a)
g.close()


g = open('g.txt', 'r+')
m = g.read()
#
num1= ', '.join(nums)
print("Исходные числа в файле f: ",n)
print("Числа в файле g: ",num1)
g.close
f.close
```

Результат работы программы

```
Исходные числа в файле f:  234, -5 , 45, 2, 234, 0, 0
Числа в файле g:  0, 234, -5, 2, 45
```

Программа работает, но нужно ее переделать так, чтобы f.read() не было в переменной n.
Так же нужно сделать ввод чисел в файл f c клавиатуры.
Как можно изменить код чтобы  исправить эти проблемы?

Comment: Так и в чем состоит ваш вопрос? Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов.

Comment: Немного переделал.
По-моему все понятно  и доступно написано

Comment: Вы не вопрос спрашиваете, а просите за вас задание доделать - чувствуете разницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Программа работает, но нужно ее переделать так, чтобы f.read() не было
> в переменной n. Так же нужно сделать ввод чисел в файл f c клавиатуры.

Замените:

```
n = f.read()
```

На

```
n = input("Input: ")
```